# Blumenthal 0-1 law

Tags: pr.probability, levy-processes

Let us define the following two stopping time $\tau_B=\inf\{t\geq 0: X_t\in B\}, \tau'_B=\inf\{t> 0: X_t\in B\}$, where $\tau_B$ is entrance time and $\tau'_B$ is hitting time. It is clear $\tau_B=\tau'_B, \mathbb{P}-a.s.$. By the book [Levy process](http://www.maphysto.dk/oldpages/events/LevyBranch2000/) by Bertoin P22, when $B$ is closed $\tau_B=\tau'_B$ may fail on $\partial B$. These point is called irregular point of B. When our starting point $x$ is irregular point of $B$, using Bulmenthal 0-1 law,  $\mathbb{P}(\tau'_B>0)=1$.

I don't understand how to use Bulmenthal 0-1 law?  Is there someone to explain a little bit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\newcommand\F{\mathcal F}\newcommand\N{\mathbb N}$First, some preliminary remarks:

1. Your link to Bertoin's book is not very good. Here is a link with a [better reference to the book](https://www.ams.org/bull/1998-35-04/S0273-0979-98-00761-7/S0273-0979-98-00761-7.pdf).
2. It is Blumenthal, not Bulmenthal.
3. It is not true that "when $B$ is closed $\tau_B=\tau'_B$ is failed on $\partial B$". This kind of failure may occur only at some (not all) points on $\partial B$, which are then called irregular points for $B$.
4. In Bertoin's book, $(X_t)_{t\ge0}$ is a right-continuous Lévy process, and $\F_t$ is the completion of the sigma-field generated by $(X_s\colon0\le s\le t)$. According to the book, let $T_B:=\tau_B$ and $T'_B:=\tau'_B$.

Now, to your question, "how to use Bulmenthal 0-1 law":

Let $B$ be a closed set. By part (iii) of Corollary 8 on p. 22 in Bertoin's book, $T'_B$ is a stopping time and hence $[T'_B=0]=[T'_B\le0]\in\F_0$, where $[\cdots]$ means the event $\cdots$. So, by the definition of $\F_t$ cited above in Remark 4, we see that $P_x(T'_B=0)$ is $0$ or $1$ for any $x$. Suppose now that a point $x\in\partial B$ is irregular for $B$. Then $P_x(T_B=T'_B)\ne1$, while $P_x(T_B=0)=1$. So, $P_x(T'_B=0)\ne1$. Thus, $P_x(T'_B=0)=0$.

In the above proof we did not explicitly use the Blumenthal 0-1 law, which states that the filtration $(\F_t)$ is right-continuous at $0$, that is, $\F_{0+}=\F_0$. However, in the proof in Bertoin's book of the fact that $T'_B$ is a stopping time he used (not quite explicitly) Proposition 4 on p. 18 in that book, which states that the filtration $(\F_t)$ is right-continuous at all real $t\ge0$, and the proof of Proposition 4 on p. 18 in that book is based on Kolmogorov's 0-1 law. So, this reference in Bertoin's book to the Blumenthal 0-1 law is indeed imprecise and possibly confusing.

Comment: thank you for your helpful comment. Can you explain a little bit your third comment? For my opinion if B is closed the starting point x $\in \partial B$. $\tau_B=0$,but $\tau'_B$ can not happened. How do you understand?

Comment: If it is possible to explain a little bit of intuition Blumenthal 0-1law. I checked lots of  explaintion but I still can not understand it intuitively.

Comment: In fact, I try to find what is exactly the interction of all sigma algebra t>0.

Comment: @CalculusFractional : To understand regular/irregular points better, I suggest reading Chapter 8 of the book Brownian Motion by Mörters and Peres, in particular, Theorem 8.3 and Example 8.32 there.

Comment: @CalculusFractional : Blumental's 0-1 law, at least for Lévy processes, is based, as I said, on Kolmogorov's 0-1 law, which is eventually reduced to the obvious statement that, if an event is independent of itself, then its probability must be $0$ or $1$.

Comment: @CalculusFractional : As I wrote, by Proposition 4 on p. 18 in Bertoin's book, $\bigcap_{t>0}\mathcal F_t=\mathcal F_0$, and $\mathcal F_0$ is the set of all sets of outer probability $0$ and the complements of those sets.